How to Include Specific Subdirectories with lsyncd while excluding their parent directory?
I'm using lsyncd to sync some data on a Linux server. I've set up an exclude list at /etc/lsyncd/excludes.txt and specified that the /test2024/ directory should be excluded. However, I want to include certain subdirectories within /test2024/, specifically /test2024/test1/, /test2024/test2/, and /test2024/test3/.
Is there a way to include these specific subdirectories while still excluding the parent directory '/test2024/'?
settings {
   logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
   statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
   nodaemon   = false,
   statusInterval = 10,
   maxProcesses = 80,
   delay = 5
}

sync{
  default.rsync,
  source="/mnt/datadrive/",
  target="user@<ip_address>",
  excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd/excludes.txt",
  rsync = {
        binary = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        links = true,
        archive = true,
        acls = true,
        owner = true,
        group = true,
        perms = true,
},
delete = true
}

sync{
  default.rsync,
  source="/mnt/datadrive/",
  target="user@<ip_address>",
  excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd/excludes.txt",
  rsync = {
        binary = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        links = true,
        archive = true,
        acls = true,
        owner = true,
        group = true,
        perms = true,
},
delete = true
}

